# Python Serial function returns incomplete list of items.

Tags: python, serial-port

I have a function that sends a command to a device connected on the serial port, then saves to an ini file.  However, I've come to find out that it hasn't been returning ALL of the lines.  Below is the code:

```
    def get_config():
        config.read("config/map.ini")
        ser = serial.Serial(3)
        ser.write(bytes("D" + '\r\n', encoding='ascii'))
        time.sleep(1)
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            r = ser.readline()
            r = r.decode('UTF-8').replace('\r\n', '')
            r = r.split()
            print("map", r[0], r[1].replace('V', ''))

        f = open("config/map.ini", "w")
        config.write(f)
        ser.close()
```

This is what's returned:

```
    001 = 013
    002 = 015
    003 = 028
    004 = 027
    005 = 015
    ... (save space)
    070 = 013
```

When using Putty to send the "D" command, I get the above list, but actually, the list is supposed to go all the way to '112 = ###'.  Is there something I'm missing that is making the output stop half way through?

Comment: maybe add a small sleep in your loop as it exits as soon as there is no data in the pipe... which may/maynot be when you think it is

Comment: Probably not the solution but - don't sleep between reads. Use select.select() to block while waiting for new data if you don't want to use a thread or some fangled event based notification library.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: http://pyserial.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pyserial/trunk/pyserial/examples/enhancedserial.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only getting the data that arrived in the time during your sleep and the time to read things once you get caught up then `inWaiting` will return 0 even if there are more characters on the way - you either need to keep trying to read until some time limit or until an end of message character - possibly both.  Try:

```
def get_config():
    config.read("config/map.ini")
    ser = serial.Serial(3)
    ser.write(bytes("D" + '\r\n', encoding='ascii'))
    time.sleep(1)
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        r = ser.readline()
        r = r.decode('UTF-8').replace('\r\n', '')
        r = r.split()
        config.set("map", r[0], r[1].replace('V', ''))
        time.sleep(0.01)

    f = open("config/map.ini", "w")
    config.write(f)
    ser.close()
```

It's not ideal but should confirm that this is the problem.

Comment: When adding `time.sleep(0.01)` I get: 
  _File "mondo.py", line 21, in get_config_
_IndexError: list index out of range_

line 21 is `config.set("map", r[0], r[1].replace('V', ''))

Comment: You are getting a line with <2 characters on it and will need to cope with that.

Comment: When I change line 21 to `print` instead of `config.set` I get the list printed out all the way to 112, then the IndexError.

Comment: I wrapped line 21 with `if len(r) > 1:` and it fixed the IndexError.  Thanks!